# Symfony controller not working

Tags: php, symfony

I am very new to symfony and started learning by following their instructions on the website. I created the lucky number controller, but it is not working as I had hoped.

Here is the code for the `LuckyController.php` file I added. I am getting a **404 error page** at the URL `localhost/testing/web/lucky/number`.

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I missed a step or if I was just suppose to create the controller. I am using *Symfony 3.1 standard edition*. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Symfony will rewrite URL from localhost/testing/web/lucky/number to localhost/testing/web/app.php/lucky/number to execute the controler. The rewrite is configured in .htaccess in web folder.
If Apache ignores that .htaccess, it will lead to above issue.

**How to check if Apache ignores .htaccess?**

Add a test line on top of .htaccess and go to the URL. If Apache is using .htaccess it will lead to an error because .htaccess syntax is wrong. If there's no error (still get 404) then Apache is not using .htaccess.

**Solution**

Generally, Apache ignores the .htaccess file because of the following Apache configuration AllowOverride none. Check your virtual host configuration and add/amend to AllowOverride All.

Example

```
<Directory /var/www/site/example.com/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

PS: I found the way to check and fix .htaccess here https://docs.bolt.cm/3.4/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works

Comment: Kind of an old question, but I like that you answered in a civilized (quite rare here at stack overflow) manner. I switched to node.js and Spring for my api development needs. They are less confusing and result in a finished product faster.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you're using the production environment in your request. Make sure your cache is clear or use the dev environment at:

```
localhost/testing/web/app_dev.php/lucky/number
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! Is ther any way to get this url to not use add_dev.php? That is super clunky.

Comment: @JoshuaBlevins if you use Symfonys Twig function path it doesn't really matter at it sorts out if you're on dev or prod. `{{ path('some_route_name', ['id' => 1]) }}`. Then it's just to open app_dev.php when you're developing locally and all routing should work

Comment: Awesome sauce! I have been beating my head against a wall over thinking that my code was not working.

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua Blevins its nice to see you come to symfony and try its first ever beginners code.

Here you have to change your `app.php` located in **web** folder of your project. Open and turn the false option to true, it will enable your project to run in production environment.

Moreover every controller of symfony extended from the base controller.

Try this:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php

// ...
// --> add this new use statement
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

you can also test your rout by just `echo "hello world!`" in the controller.

reference [Create your First Page in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html)